# Pytorch: model.parameters() returns an empty list

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

Im trying to build and train a very simple 2 layer neural network below
I am following the template that pytorch tutorials have ( https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/buildmodel_tutorial.html)

The only difference is that I am initializing the model weights

```py
from torch import nn
# create a two layer FCNN, avoid ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
class img2latent(nn.Module):
    def __int__(self):
        super(img2latent,self).__init__()
        self.neuralDim=len(X_train[0])
        self.latentDim=len(Y_train[0])
        self.hiddenDim=self.neuralDim
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(self.neuralDim,self.hiddenDim)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(self.hiddenDim,self.latentDim)
        # INTITIALISE THE WEIGHTS, FC1 WITH ONES, FC2 WITH PARAMETERS OF RIDGE
        self.fc1.weight.data.fill_(1)
        self.fc1.bias.data.fill_(0)
        self.fc2.weight.data=ridge.coef_
        self.fc2.bias.data=ridge.intercept_
    
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.fc1(x)
        # add reLU
        x=torch.relu(x)        
        x=self.fc2(x)
        return x
  
    

def train_loop(model,loss_fn, optimizer):
    model.train()
    # do full batch gradient descent
    pred=model(X_train)
    loss=loss_fn(pred,Y_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    return loss.item()
    
    
fullmodel=img2latent()
# SEND TO GPU
fullmodel=fullmodel.to(device)
# take mse loss + l2 regularaisation  on the weights of the second layer
loss=nn.MSELoss()
optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(fullmodel.parameters(),lr=0.01,weight_decay=0.01)
for t in range(1000):
    loss=train_loop(fullmodel,loss,optimizer)
    if t%100==0:
        print(t,f"{loss:0.2f}",end='\t')

# predict the latents for train data and do a correlation
pred=fullmodel(X_train)
```

but for some reason i get `ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list`, which means the `fullmodel.parameters()` is returning an empty list.I checked this and this is indeed true.

I tried looking it up on stackoverflow, but I couldnt find an example where the parameters are itself empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in your constructor

```
    def __int__(self):
```

should be

```
    def __init__(self):
```

so your code actually has no constructor, and thus is just generating an empty nn.module which indeed has no parameters.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering questions that are due to typos; leave a comment and vote to close them as such instead.